# SQL Query Help: Selecting based on another select only returning one row

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am running into some slight trouble with the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM SaleItems WHERE SalesID = (SELECT SaleID FROM Sale WHERE TotalPrice > (SELECT AVG(TotalPrice) FROM Sale))
```

The second part of the query:

```
SELECT SaleID FROM Sale WHERE TotalPrice > (SELECT AVG(TotalPrice) FROM Sale)
```

returns 5 entries.

But, when I run the first query, I only get one result back.  It only bases the WHERE off of only the *first* result from the second part of the query.

How can I solve this?  I want the first query to return all where the SalesID is *any* of the 5 SaleIDs returned by the second part, not just the first row.

Comment: Didn't it throw an error "Subquery return more than one rows "?

Answer (score 2):

Use `IN`:

```
SELECT * FROM SaleItems WHERE SalesID IN (SELECT SaleID FROM Sale WHERE TotalPrice > (SELECT AVG(TotalPrice) FROM Sale))
```